# Is there a way to increase the efficiency of shared_ptr by storing the reference count inside the controlled object?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

This is becoming a common pattern in my code, for when I need to manage an object that needs to be noncopyable because either A. it is "heavy" or B. it is an operating system resource, such as a critical section:

```
class Resource;

class Implementation : public boost::noncopyable
{
    friend class Resource;
    HANDLE someData;
    Implementation(HANDLE input) : someData(input) {};
    void SomeMethodThatActsOnHandle() {
        //Do stuff
    };
public:
    ~Implementation() { FreeHandle(someData) };
};

class Resource
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Implementation> impl;
public:
    Resource(int argA) explicit {
        HANDLE handle = 
            SomeLegacyCApiThatMakesSomething(argA);
        if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            throw SomeTypeOfException();
        impl.reset(new Implementation(handle));
    };
    void SomeMethodThatActsOnTheResource() {
        impl->SomeMethodThatActsOnTheHandle();
    };
};
```

This way, shared_ptr takes care of the reference counting headaches, allowing `Resource` to be copyable, even though the underlying handle should only be closed once all references to it are destroyed.

However, it seems like we could save the overhead of allocating shared_ptr's reference counts and such separately if we could move that data inside `Implementation` somehow, like boost's intrusive containers do.

If this is making the premature optimization hackles nag some people, I actually agree that I don't need this for my current project. But I'm curious if it is possible.

Comment: Boost has an `intrusive_ptr`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html But I'm not posting as an answer because I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Also, THIS IS TOTALLY PREMATURE OPTIMIZATION WTF ARE YOU DOING? DON'T YOU KNOW KNUTH'S QUOTE? PREMATURE OPTIMIZATION IS THE ROOT OF ALL EVIL? HM, HAVEN'T YOU HEARD IT YET? NOW YOU HAVE.

Comment: @GMan: LOL! Though @others reading this, I believe the quote is "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil". I'm stipulating this is a 3% case.

Comment: I would change your pattern so that the whole of the implementation is in the Implementation class. Once that is done you do not need a separate Resource class to hold the smart pointer. You could use a base class of Implementation to provide a synchronized ref count. The two functions at global scope have to be provided per class and defined in the same namespace as your class so you might want a pair of macros for that, or a template per namespace.

Comment: @Permaquid: That defeats the purpose of putting Implementation by itself in the first place. The reason for the Resource class is the assumption that Implementation must be noncopyable for some reason, for example a CRITICAL_SECTION object. If it was copyable, I could just put the HANDLE into a boost::shared_ptr<void> and be done with it.

Comment: To be fair, my example doens't make that super duper clear :(

Comment: What about shared_ptr<void, Deleter> allows the resource to be copied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A partial solution is to use `make_shared` to create your `shared_ptr`s.  For example,

```
auto my_thing = std::make_shared<Thing>();
```

instead of

```
auto my_thing = std::shared_ptr<Thing>(new Thing);
```

It's still non-intrusive, so nothing else needs to change.  Good implementations of `make_shared` combine the memory allocation for the reference count and the object itself.  That saves a memory allocation and keeps the count close to the object for better locality.  It's not quite as efficient as something like `boost:intrusive_ptr`, but it's worth considering.

Comment: I can't do this because the shared pointer is constructed as a member of `Resource` before I have constructed the argument needed for `Implementation`. You end up constructing a shared_ptr to NULL, and then assigning it a new shared_ptr allocated with make_shared. The allocation cost was already paid by by impl's call before the constructor started executing.

Comment: @BillyONeal: A default constructed shared_ptr shouldn't need to allocate anything until reset is called. It should be very cheap.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) which is designed to work on a class with an embedded reference count.

Non-tested example based on [example here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/boostsmartptr.aspx):

```
class Resource; 

class Implementation : public boost::noncopyable 
{ 
    friend class Resource;
    HANDLE someData;
    int refCount; // The reference count.
    Implementation(HANDLE input) : someData(input) { refCount = 0; }; 
    void SomeMethodThatActsOnHandle() { 
        //Do stuff 
    }; 
public: 
    ~Implementation() { FreeHandle(someData) }; 
};

intrusive_ptr_add_ref(Implementation* imp) { imp->refCount++; }
intrusive_ptr_release(Implementation* imp) { if(--imp->refCount) == 0) delete imp; }

class Resource 
{ 
    boost::intrusive_ptr<Implementation> impl; 
public: 
    Resource(int argA) explicit { 
        HANDLE handle =  
            SomeLegacyCApiThatMakesSomething(argA); 
        if (handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
            throw SomeTypeOfException(); 
        impl.reset(new Implementation(handle)); 
    }; 
    void SomeMethodThatActsOnTheResource() { 
        impl->SomeMethodThatActsOnTheHandle(); 
    }; 
};
```

Comment: Can you provide an example (preferably the above one edited) that uses `intrusive_ptr`? I saw that in the docs, but the documentation is a bit opaque...

Comment: Don't forget to make the increment and decrement-and-test atomic.

Comment: @Permaquid: In a multithreaded environment that is needed yes. My code above is *not* intended to be thread safe.

Comment: @Permaquid: Given that it's not atomic in boost::shared_ptr I don't think it's really an issue here.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Yes it is, mostly as a lock-free implementation. Search for *lock-free* on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) page.

Comment: The question mentioned critical sections. My comment is just a reminder to the questioner, based on that. @BillyONeal the reference counts are managed using atomic operations in shared_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

you can save some overhead by simply getting rid of the two classes and having just one and typedefing a shared ptr to it - this is the idom i use all the time

```
 class Resource
 {
      ...
 };
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<Resource> ResourcePtr;
```

Comment: That still requires users to choose whether to use the pointer variant or not. I'd rather avoid that. Plus it does not answer the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the overhead of distinct memory allocations for your object and the reference counter, you could try to use [make_shared](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html). That's what its for.

Comment: I can't do that because shared_ptr is constructed before I know what to assign to it in my constructor.

Comment: @BillyONeal: So? I don't see why make_shared isn't applicable. Creating a shared_ptr that points to nothing doesn't require a ref counter.

Comment: I think this would be just as efficient as using an `intrusive_ptr`. `intrusive_ptr` is good for managing resources that already have a reference count like COM objects. But I don't think there is much to be gained by explicitly coding a reference count in when it's not needed. As is mentioned here, `make_shared` should allocate the reference count and `Implementation` in one go, so that step should be no different than  newing up an `Implementation` that contains a reference count inside itself.